# Push top half of image outside of card

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am attempting to create the following design in Ionic:

[image]

Currently, I am specifically trying to push the top half of an image past the top of the card and have the image be about 80% of the width of the card.

How can I push the top half of the image outside of the card?

I have created a [StackBlitz for this issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5ssv9l).

**Edit:** [I have been able to make the image protrude the top half of the card](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wp2qfv?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss) but the image is overlapping text and other images. How can I push the card down where the top half contains the bottom half of the image and the bottom half contains the additional text, images, etc.?

Here is my CSS:

```
.card {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  overflow: visible;

  div {
    position: absolute;
    top: -95px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }


  img:not(.castImg) {
    width: 80%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    display: block;
    margin: -100px auto 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup or code **here within your question** that allows us to duplicate the issue: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

looking at the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5ssv9l?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.scss)  Made 2 changes in the home.scss file... play around with 17% which is an arbitrary number on both places

```
.card {
      margin-left: 30px;
      margin-right: 30px;
      width: auto;
      border-radius: 8px;
      margin-top: 17%; /* Change 1a */
      overflow: visible; /* Change 1b */
      img:not(.castImg) {
        width: 80%;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: -17%; /* Change 2 */
        border-radius: 8px;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
      }
      ion-card-title {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }
```